# problems with mina / netty tcp endpoint in camel (tcp socket server endpoint)

Tags: apache-camel, netty, apache-mina, jbossfuse

i want to connect a soap webservice to a tcp enpoint. The tcp endpoint has to be a tcp socket server that accepts clients.

now i have for example this route

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:myendpoint" />

<to uri="netty:tcp://localhost:port" />
```

this doesnt work because what i have found out

`<from uri="netty:tcp://localhost:port" />`       this configures it as server socket where clients can connect

`<to uri="netty:tcp://localhost:port" />`          this configures it as client that can connect to a server socket

is there any way to configure netty/mina etc as a server socket and not a client with the `<to />` tag?

or might anyone have an idea for a workaround for this?

someone else already had a similar problem according to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-1077 "tcp client mode / server mode determined by "to" or "from" elements limits usability." But i dont think anything has happened since then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to send the response from the soap service to tcp server.
You can setup the route like this

```
from("direct:start").to("cxf:xxx").to("netty:xxx");
```

Comment: sry about that looks like i somehow messed up with the example code. I corrected it now and hope its more clear what i mean. Your answer would be the most logical approach but this creates a tcp client and i need a tcp server.

Comment: If you want to create a tcp server, how can your tcp endpoint talk to that tcp server?

Comment: for example if i have this configured from("cxf:xxx").to("netty:xxx") --> (already existing tcp client that cannot be changed), if i set it up this way the already existing client cannot connect to my netty endpoint, because it also gets configured as client. And this is why i am confused and wondering whether there a workaround or not.

Comment: Can you change your netty endpoint? Current camel-netty producer cannot be configured to a server.

Comment: this is what im currently trying to do. For starters i wrote a processor that sends out the message to everyone connected and now im going to write an endpoint thats either the opposite of camel netty, meaning producer = server and consumer = client or ill make it in a way so you can decide via argument what it role its going to be